# Asking subjective questions that encourage discussion

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, subjective

I want to ask a question about the C++11 `auto` keyword in order to get people's opinions on why it should be used, and to post my concerns about it. Naturally, this won't be a good question for Stack Overflow since it will encourage discussion and there will be no single "right" answer.

Does Stack Overflow have some sort of "forum" site where discussions are more appropriate? If not, where should I ask my question?

Comment: you could try the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com)...

Comment: I think it might just be possible to phrase this question such that it is not closed for being too subjective. After all, it should explain *why* and *how*, on a technical level, and not end up in discussion. We have quite a few guidelines for *good* subjective questions. [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: @slhck I nominate you to do it =)

Comment: @casperOne I don't know enough about these topics to do it, but I guess the OP will find good input from MSO on how to phrase it if they want to go ahead ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subjective stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/subjective-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically just a summary of the comments on your question, which really deserve an answer of their own.

If you want to engage in a free-form discussion about the `auto` keyword, the best place to do that would be the [Stack Overflow chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) (specifically the [C++ chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)).

If you have a question on *a specific aspect* of the `auto` keyword, I think that you could make a reasonable Stack Overflow question about it. Just keep your question focused and answerable in an objective way.

Alternately, you could start a discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) to help you refine a question that would be a good fit for posting on Stack Overflow.